# What is the current, AD 2020, stat of difference between openSuSE and SuSE distros?

Tags: centos, rhel, opensuse, distribution-choice, suse

Can someone describe the current differences between SuSE and openSuSE.

Is openSuSE just a clone of SuSE, just like CentOS made a clone of RedHat when RedHat went fully commercial?

Note: before turning me to the other questions please take into account that they are several years old and the state should have likely changed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the openSUSE [FAQ](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:FAQ), specifically: [“What is the difference between openSUSE and SUSE’s enterprise offerings”](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_openSUSE_and_SUSE.27s_enterprise_offerings.3F)

There are several answers there, and since you seem to distrust other answers on this site, maybe getting it from the horses mouth would be better.